# PageTurner Build In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Hello i want to Build PageTurner Reading Activity in eclipse Android.
I follow https://github.com/NightWhistler/PageTurner , and do exactly the things mentioned in the video on this link youtube.com/watch?v=jhSvwpwPFoY
But i failed to build it. I cloned the ActionBarSherlock and then using maven install it, but it failed after 25-30 min. Same with PageTurner clone happened.
And i used m2E plugin in eclipse. but it also gives many errors, espacially in POM.xml.

Please help me, to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is a bit late, but unless you're absolutely forced to use Eclipse, I'd strongly recommend switching to IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

It has much better Maven support and will import PageTurner in just a few clicks.